# Не использовать UNION и вывести 2 последних значения пользователя

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Есть база юзеров и их добавленные ссылки с фиксацией времени.
Задача - средствами SQL вывести по каждому юзеру по 2 последних добавленных ссылки. UNION не выход, по словам куратора.
Через PHP я мог бы получить список пользователей и по каждому пользователю сделать запрос с LIMIT 2, но это слишком много нагрузки. У куратора есть решение, но он не делится)

Гугл тоже не делится

Пробовал так:
SELECT id, user_id, url, MAX(add_date) FROM test GROUP BY user_id;
Но здесь выводиться только 1 результат по сгруппированному user_id, а нужно 2.

Вот пример базы:

[image: Пример базы]

Вот что нужно получить:

[image: Нужный результат]

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Ожидаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия. Без картинок.

Answer (score 1):

В ранних версиях MySQL это может не работать, но в современных работает.

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, user_id INT, url CHAR(255), add_date DATE);

INSERT test (user_id, url, add_date) VALUES(1, "url1", NOW());
INSERT test (user_id, url, add_date) VALUES(2, "url1", NOW());
INSERT test (user_id, url, add_date) VALUES(1, "url2", NOW());
INSERT test (user_id, url, add_date) VALUES(2, "url2", NOW());
INSERT test (user_id, url, add_date) VALUES(2, "url3", NOW());
INSERT test (user_id, url, add_date) VALUES(3, "url1", NOW());

SELECT SQ.* FROM
(
    SELECT
        RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY t1.user_id ORDER BY t1.id DESC) AS Rnk,  
        user_id,
        URL,
        add_date
    FROM test t1
) SQ
WHERE SQ.Rnk <= 2
ORDER BY SQ.user_id
          
/*DROP TABLE test */
```

Надеюсь, я смог Вам помочь)

Comment: Не помогли)

Это не решение

Comment: А почему не подходит? Я бы мог как то иначе переписать запрос.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/2SkXWfST5VDE

Использую MariaDB

Comment: Ааа, понял, синтаксис на MySQL похож, подумал это он.

Comment: Посмотрите изменённый запрос, это без привязки к БД, работет на всех SQL серверах.

Comment: Работает, спасибо

Правда с новым столбцом..

Comment: Вы про Rnk? Его можно не выводить) надеюсь куратор оценит)

Comment: Он уже заценил)))

Сказал что не работает должным образом, мол надо выводить последние записи - то есть сортировать

Если даже использовать `add_date` DESC - будет работать некорректно, так как RANK будет выполняться до сортировки

Comment: Не совсем понял, что имел ввиду куратор, но если не затруднит, когда он выдаст якобы правильное решение, поделитесь пожалуйста. Мне очень интересно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант через кучу джойнов:

```
select test.* from test
left join
(
select t2.user_id, max(t2.id) id2, t.id id1
from test t2
right join
(select t1.user_id, max(t1.id) id from test t1 group by t1.user_id) t
on (t.user_id = t2.user_id and t2.id < t.id)
group by user_id
) t3
on(test.id = t3.id1 or test.id = t3.id2)
where !isnull(id1)
order by test.user_id, test.id
```